# Is $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ a closed subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the extended real numbers and $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ the extended integers. My stupid question is whether $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a **closed** subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

My answer is: yes, since $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is Hausdorff and $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a compact subset: In Hausdorff spaces, compact subsets are closed.

Comment: Is the complementary open, ie. what is the topology on $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$?

Comment: By $\overline{\mathbb{Z}},$ I'm assuming you must mean $\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty, + \infty\}$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Also, we're assuming the natural topology on $\mathbb{R},$ correct? The open ball topology?

Comment: @reuns I am not sure but for the topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, I would suggest the topology whose base is given by the open intervals and the rays $(\alpha,\infty], [-\infty,\beta)$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In that case $+\infty =-\infty$ to make it Hausdorff. Anyway with one or two $\infty$ it stays obvious that $\Bbb{R-Z}$ is open, right?

Comment: What I had in mind was $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. - One has to check whether $\overline{\mathbb{R}}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. This is obviously true, say, for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the open balls. Consequently, the answer to my question in the headline is YES: :-)

Comment: $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is homeomorphic to the closed interval $[-1, 1]$ by, for example, the map $$x \mapsto \frac x{1+|x|}$$ (This is under the order topology on both, which is also the topology you described to reuns, though by the Hausdorff remark, they apparently mistook you for saying "$(\alpha, \infty]\cup[-\infty, \beta)$".) Under this map, $\overline{\Bbb Z}$ is carried to a closed set having $-1, 1$ as its only accumulation points, which are inside it. I.e., it is closed.